# greenDao @ToMany relation not working, returning 0

Tags: android, database, relational-database, greendao

I have a problem with greenDao and @ToMany relation. Drning session when i'm doing insertion to DB i can get @ToMany relation easily. My problem occurs after I'm restarting my application, list that is being returned is empty.

Daily.class

```
@Entity
public class Daily extends BaseObservable implements Parcelable {

@Id(autoincrement = true)
private Long id;

@Unique
private String tag;

@SerializedName("summary")
@Expose
private String summary;

@SerializedName("icon")
@Expose
private String icon;

@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
@ToMany(joinProperties = {
        @JoinProperty(name = "tag", referencedName = "dataTag")})
@OrderBy("id ASC")
private List<DailyData> data = new ArrayList<DailyData>();
```

DailyData.class

```
@Entity
public class DailyData extends BaseObservable implements Parcelable {

@Id(autoincrement = true)
private Long id;

@NotNull private String dataTag;
... [rest of the code]
```

Place where I'm doing insert to DB (I'm using rxjava2 to get model). I've been trying inserting it in different order but there is no affect also.

```
public void insertCityToDatabase(City city) {

    city.setName(cityLatLngList.get(getPosition()).getResult().getName());

    city.getDailyWithoutId().setTag(city.getName());
    city.getHourlyWithoutId().setTag(city.getName());

    for (HourlyData hourlyData : city.getHourlyWithoutId().getHourlyDataWithoutId()) {
        hourlyData.setDataTag(city.getName());
        daoSession.insert(hourlyData);
    }
    for (DailyData dailyData : city.getDailyWithoutId().getDataWithoutId()) {
        dailyData.setDataTag(city.getName());
        daoSession.insert(dailyData);
    }

    daoSession.insert(city.getHourlyWithoutId());
    daoSession.insert(city.getDailyWithoutId());
    daoSession.insert(city.getCurrentlyWithoutId());

    long id = daoSession.insert(city);

    eventBus.post(new NewCity(id));
}
```

Here is my DB [Daily and DailyData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8zhJ.jpg), [debuger Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAKK9.jpg)

I have also tried doing @ToMany relation by
@ToMany(referencedJoinProperty = "id") but the result is the same.

Any idea why @ToMany relation is not working?

Comment: Did you solved it? I have the same problem

Comment: No, i was forced to move from greenDao to Realm cause of this problem. Once i tried to test greenDao at new project and it was working but i have no idea why it wasn't working here.

Comment: It seems that you should have a property Daily in DailyData. In this way is similar to JPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem just now. Your Daily.class:

```
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
@ToMany(joinProperties = {
    @JoinProperty(name = "tag", referencedName = "dataTag")})
@OrderBy("id ASC")
private List<DailyData> data = new ArrayList<DailyData>();
```

and DailyData.class:

```
@Entity
public class DailyData extends BaseObservable implements Parcelable {

@Id(autoincrement = true)
private Long id;

@NotNull private String dataTag;
... [rest of the code]
```

This means that field tag in Daily.class has relation with field dataTag in DailyData.class. So when you  insert to DB:

```
for (DailyData dailyData : city.getDailyWithoutId().getDataWithoutId()){
    dailyData.setDataTag(city.getTag());//
    daoSession.insert(dailyData);
}
```

I solve the problem in this way.

Comment: I did it, but it says: "Dataz is not an entity, but it is referenced for @ToMany relation in class (field: data)";;;;; Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44082952/custom-type-in-greendao-with-pojo-class